# Setting proper Constraint for UITableViewCell content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I am using a custom cell which has two modes - normal and expanded. In normal mode cell height is 64 pt and I have an image view, 2 labels (on left) and 1 textfield (on right). And in expanded mode (when user tap), cell height is set to 97 pt and I add a stepper on right side just below the text field.

Now, I have to set the constraints in such a way that, in normal mode, text field remains in the middle of the cell while when cell is expanded it remains at its original place in normal mode.

But, if I set the middle constraint in normal mode, it remains same in expanded mode. If I remove the middle constraint in normal mode, I do not know what kind of constraint I should set to make text field remain in its original position in normal mode of cell.

Can someone suggest some options.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show a picture of your layout? In both "normal" and "expanded" mode...

Comment: You can always enable and disable any constraint

Comment: Yes, enabling/disabling constraint is fine. But in expanded mode how can I ensure that quantity text box remains at its original position and do not move even a single point.

Comment: Set a Top constraint on the Text Field, relative to the Top of the cell.

Comment: @DonMag - Added the pictures of both expanded and normal mode.

Comment: Sorry I can understand good enough, can you post a image with what you want to achieve?

Comment: @ReinierMelian - I just did!

Comment: Ahh then you must set top constraint to top of your cell as @DonMag suggest

Comment: @DonMag - But what value it should be? Because it has to match the middle of the cell. Right?

Comment: @ReinierMelian - Thats what I'm confused of. What value it should be so it matches the middle of the cell in normal mode? Even if someone changes the cell height it remains there. Or is it like, I need to hardcode it based on cell height and anytime  cell height changes, we need to adjust this top constraint constant also?

Comment: If your cell will have always the same height in collapsed mode you can easy setup your top constraint to fixed value

Comment: Do you want it vertically centered, regardless of the cell "expanded" or "normal" state? Or do you want it to stay where it is, relative to the Labels?

Comment: I want it to be vertically centred in normal (non-expanded) mode and when expanded it should not change its position at all.

Comment: @Abhinav check my last comment, I think you must setup top constraint fixed value instead of center constraint if your collapsed cell is always the same height

Comment: Yeah @ReinierMelian. It worked. But, as I said, if someone changes the cell height, top constraint constant needs to be updated. I guess there is no way out and this is the best possible way. Thanks guys!

Comment: OK - then just position it vertically centered in the cell, while the cell is at 64pt in height... add a Top constraint at that position (it will probably be 16, based on what you've shown). Then it will stay there, regardless of cell height.

Comment: Just FYI... I have set it horizontally centred and 19.5 pt away from top. And it works fine in both the modes.

Comment: If "*someone changes the cell height*" everything will need adjustment, no?

Comment: I think so :). May be this is the right way. Thanks much @DonMag!